# Generalised function template for standard library containers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I'm trying to write a simple generalised function for iteration over container elements. Every element is converted to `std::string` (no matter how) and stored in another place. The basic version was trivial:

```
template<class Container>
void ContainerWork(const Container& c)
{
    for(const auto& elem : c) {
        /* convert to string and store*/
    }
}
```

Then it became necessary to add specialisation for containers with value type `std::string` and code transformed to:

```
template<typename T, template<typename, typename> class Container, class Allocator>
void ContainerWork(Container<T, Allocator> c)
{
    for(const T& elem : c) {
        /* convert to string and store*/
    }
}

template<template<typename, typename> class Container, class Allocator>
void ContainerWork(Container<std::string, Allocator> c)
{
    for(const std::string& elem : c) {
        /* frame elem in quotes*/
    }
}
```

It works great, but now I can use only sequenced containers (`vector`, `list`, etc.), but I want also use `set` and and `unordered_set`. Any ideas how do this without "copy-paste" realisation for container with 4 params? I am trying to play with `decltype(Container)::value_type` but with no luck.

I may use most of c++11 features (compiler - VS2012 or GCC 4.8.x)

Answer (score 7):

That's why all of the standard library's algorithms work on iterators rather than containers.

You can change your core function to work on iterators rather than containers. This will require partial specialisation, which doesn't exist for function templates, so we'll use the delegate-to-class trick:

```
template <typename It>
void DoIteratorWork(It start, It end)
{
  DoIteratorWork_Impl<It, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>::call(start, end);
}

template <typename It, typename ValueType>
struct DoIteratorWork_Impl
{
  static void call(It start, It end)
  {
    for (; start != end; ++start) {
      // operate on *it
    }
  }
};

template <typename It>
struct DoIteratorWork_Impl<It, std::string>
{
  static void call(It start, It end)
  {
    for (; start != end; ++start) {
      // operate on *it
    }
  }
};
```

If you really want to, you can then create a wrapper around this:

```
template <class Container>
void DoContainerWork(const Container& c)
{
  using std::begin; using std::end; // enable ADL of begin and end
  return DoIteratorWork(begin(c), end(c));
}
```

Comment: That's elegant. I'd suggest to add `inline` modifier to the `DoIteratorWork` function.

Comment: @DarkWanderer If you think your compiler pays any attention whatsoever to it as an optimisation hint (I'd guess most don't), feel free to do so. But as it's a template, it would have 0 impact language-wise.

Comment: Visual Studio compiler has "only __inline" setting for the inlining. Yes, I think the compiler does look at the `inline` keyword when this is enabled. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx

Comment: @DarkWanderer OK, fair enough. Still, I would consider using this setting for an optimised build to be grossly suboptimal ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this example, I already thinking about iterator-type functions, but i was limited by existing interface (with Container type). Now i clearly understand how can I make wrappers for current code :)

Comment: `It::value_type` is the wrong thing.  Use `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type`.  Same with `c.begin()`, it should be `using std::begin; begin(c)` -- always test iterator code to see if it works on raw C arrays and you'll catch a bunch of mistakes like that.  (And don't use `std::begin` directly if you can help it, so 3rd party containers with ADL `begin` methods can be found)

Comment: @Yakk You're right of course, thanks. I'll edit the answer tomorrow (no time now), or you can do it yourself if you feel like it.

Comment: @Angew the final think I'd do is turn it back into a container-based algorithm.  The iterator based versions just exist to extract trait information about the contents of the container: there is no real advantage to manually doing the loop instead of `for( auto&& x:c )`  But that would be a radical change!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `variadic-templates`, something like

```
template<typename T, template<typename...> class Container, typename... Args>
void ContainerWork(Container<T, Args...> c)
{
}

template<template<typename...> class Container, typename... Args>
void ContainerWork(Container<std::string, Args...> c)
{
}
```

And probably you can of course use simple dispatch

```
template<typename Container>
void ContainerWork(Container c, 
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename Container::value_type,
std::string>::value>::type* = 0)
{
}

template<typename Container>
void ContainerWork(Container c,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename Container::value_type,
std::string>::value>::type* = 0)
{
}
```

But anyway, if difference is only in call to convert function - you can simply overload it for `T` and for `string`, version for `string` will simple return this string.

Also you can use `SFINAE` with C++11 `decltype` feature

```
template<typename Container>
auto ContainerWork(Container c) -> 
decltype(c.begin(),
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename Container::value_type,
std::string>::value, void>::type())
{
}

template<typename Container>
auto ContainerWork(Container c) ->
decltype(c.begin(),
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename Container::value_type,
std::string>::value, void>::type())
{
}
```

Comment: Does not compute... err... compile under VS2012

Comment: @DarkWanderer Use VS2013 or later for variadic templates.

Comment: @rubenvb: OP mentioned VS2012, hence the comment

Comment: Did I mention it's a bad answer anywhere? No. I'm just making a warning to whoever will stumble upon this answer later.

Comment: I look for better way to do it. VT no supported by VS2012, but if this worked on VS2013 and gcc 4.8 I think it may be best solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thinking about dispatch, but did not think about additional parameter with pointer type :) Try this today.

Comment: Why does the order and structure of the `template` passed in *really* matter?  What matters is what you can *do* with the passed in container, not pattern matching on the declaration of the type of the container.  Also note that ideally passing `int a[10]` should work with your code: relying on `::value_type` existing is suboptimal.

Answer (score 2):

```
// implement the bodies as functors to allow for partial
// specialization for value_type:
template <class value_type>
struct DoContainerWorkImpl {
  template<typename Container>
  void operator()(const Container& c) const
  {
    for (auto&& x : c) {
      // code
    }
  }
};
template <>
struct DoContainerWorkImpl<std::string> {
  template<typename Container>
  void operator()(const Container& c) const
  {
    for (std::string const& x : c) {
      // code
    }
  }
};

template <class Container>
void DoContainerWork(const Container& c)
{
  using std::begin; // enable ADL of begin
  // extract the iterator for the container c:
  typedef typename std::decay<decltype( std::begin(c) )>::type iterator;
  // extract the value type of the container:
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type value_type;
  DoContainerWorkImpl<value_type>()( c );
}
```

another approach would involve making the algorithm one thing, and determining if we want to call the conversion within the body of the algorithm using a traits class or other technique "locally".

Here is a stab at that approach:

```
 // convert non-strings:
 template<typename T>
 std::string as_string( T&& t )
 {
   // converting code goes here
 }
 // block dangling rvalues:
 std::string as_string( std::string&& s ) { return std::move(s); }
 // pass lvalues through:
 std::string const& as_string( std::string const& s ) { return s; }
 std::string const& as_string( std::string& s ) { return s; }
```

now, we do this in your loop body:

```
for(auto&& elem : c) {
  std::string const& s = as_string(std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem));
  // code using s as a string
}
```

which compiles to a noop (or, at worst a few moves) if the container is a container of `std::string`, and to converting code if it is not.

Lifetime extension of temporaries assigned to references keeps any temporary generated `std::string` around, and lvalue lifetime of the iterator keeps the "string container whose iterators return references" lifetime long enough.

Comment: He wanted to add quotes to strings so `std::string as_string(std::string)` isn't just a copy.  Otherwise, this is the solution I think is best.  Looping through the elements shouldn't be replicated (especially if you have to duplicate the code around the conversion in the loop too) and you shouldn't assume that a container you'll receive will be templated with the first parameter being your value_type.

Comment: @GuyGreer ah, I missed that -- I thought he was trying to avoid needless copies of the `std::string`!  The same plan applies in this case: you do a `as_string` or `std::string s = quote_if_string(elem)` and have everything else be oblivious to the type of the `elem`.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, i mean "some work with string", e.g. quoting. Do we need "perfect forwarding" for `as_string` in this case? Any chance what `elem`in `for` be a `rvalue`?

Comment: @ShaKeSPeaR a range of input iterators could iterate by value (temporary), and would otherwise be a valid argument to your code.  I just have a tendency to write code to be more generic than it needs to be.

Comment: @Yakk I ask because I have a similar piece of code (many `to_string` for user types) and use signature like `to_stirng(const T& val)`. Now I think about switching to `T&&`...

Comment: @ShaKeSPeaR do you have a case it would be faster?  Overloading is probably better than specialization, and a over greedy perfect forwarder can get in the way of overloading.

Comment: @Yakk No, it was done for compatibility with older compilers (not c  11) and wide range of types, including "heavy" user types. But sometimes it leading to stupidity, e.g. for enums. I think switch to T&& increase the speed by using rvalue. But I'm confused by fact that for each type I should do two specializations (for lvalue and rvalue)

Answer (score 1):

As far as  I understand this, you could just use `std::for_each` with a polymorphic functor:

```
namespace detail {

    template<typename T>
    std::string do_conversion(const T& item) {
        // convert to string
    }

    template<>
    std::string do_conversion<std::string>(const std::string& item) {
        // frame in quotes
    }
}

struct convert_to_string {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(const T& item) {
        // delegate to free function in namespace scope, because otherwise we 
        // cannot specialize
        std::string result = detail::do_conversion(item);
    }
};

// in calling code

std::for_each(std::begin(container), std::end(container), convert_to_string{});
```

Does this work for you?